# Not all icons appearing on openSUSE

Tags: linux, icons, opensuse, lxde

So, I recently switched from Linux Mint to openSUSE because openSUSE was more lightweight and customizable in my opinion. I installed all of my favorite applications from LM onto my openSUSE laptop, but ran into an issue regarding icons.

Not all of the icons are appearing. Instead they appear as a gray box with a red cross in it. (I would post an image, but apparently I need more reputation to do that...)

I've installed all the icon packs and themes from the repositories, but the icons still refuse to work. A Google search shows that I have all of the popular icon packs installed already. What am I missing here?

Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 1):

You might need to update manually the icon cache, with something like this as root:

```
gtk-update-icon-cache -q -t -f /usr/share/icons/gnome
```

(replacing `gnome` with the directory containing icons which aren't displayed)
That say, the package manager post-install scripts should do that for you.

Comment: Thank you for the help! Is there an easy way to tell what directory the missing icons are from? Thanks!

Comment: Don't know, which icons are missing ? Oh, and with this solution (which may not work), I'm assuming it is in a GTK+ environment.

Comment: The icons from all the gnome programs are missing... I've tried running the command on all the gnome icon packages, however...